# Safe solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Assume a table structure of MyTable(MyTableId NVARCHAR(MAX) PRIMARY KEY, NumberOfInserts INTEGER).

I often need to either update i.e. increment a counter of an existing record, or insert a new record if it doesn't exist with a value of 0 for NumberOfInserts.

Essentially:

```
IF (MyTableId exists)
    run UPDATE command
ELSE
    run INSERT command
```

My concern is losing data due to race conditions, etc.

What's the **safest** way to write this?

I need it to be 100% accurate if possible, and willing to sacrifice speed where necessary.

Comment: You could look into using the MERGE command, it combined update, insert and delete all at once. Couple of observations, please don't call that column 'key' it's a reserved word in SQL Server. Also, are you using that as your primary key? If so, NVARCHAR(MAX) is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement can perform both `UPDATE` and `INSERT` (and `DELETE` if needed).

Even though it is a single atomic statement, it is important to use `HOLDLOCK` query hint to prevent race condition. There is a blog post [“UPSERT” Race Condition With MERGE](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx) by Dan Guzman where he explains in great details how it works and provides a test script to verify it.

The query itself is straight-forward:

```
DECLARE @NewKey NVARCHAR(MAX) = ...;

MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS Dst
USING 
(
    SELECT @NewKey AS NewKey
) AS Src
ON Src.NewKey = Dst.[Key]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET NumberOfInserts = NumberOfInserts + 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
(
    [Key]
    ,NumberOfInserts
)
VALUES
(
    @NewKey
    ,0
);
```

---

Of course, you can also use explicit two-step approach with a separate check if a row exists and separate `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements. Just make sure to wrap them all in a transaction with appropriate table locking hints.

See [Conditional INSERT/UPDATE Race Condition](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx) by Dan Guzman for details.

Comment: Be careful using MERGE...there's a ton of issues with it:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/