# SQL Server error : violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_table'. - IF NOT EXISTS NOT WORKING

Tags: c#, sql-server

I use `IF NOT EXISTS` in my SQL Server 2016 query, but it seems it has been ignored...

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
              FROM dbo.eventmarkets 
              WHERE it = '59902852C13-1763_1_3')
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.eventmarkets(it, ov, market, eventid, status, marketid) 
   VALUES ('59902852C13-1763_1_3', '59902852C13-1763_1_3', 'google some', '15312738825C13_1_3', 0, 1763)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.eventmarkets 
    SET ov = '59902852C13-1763_1_3',
        market = 'google some',
        eventid = '15312738825C13_1_3',
        status = 0,
        marketid = 1763 
    WHERE it = '59902852C13-1763_1_3' 
END
```

where transactionscope with snapshot and readcommit enabled

Any help appreciated

Comment: you have to take update lock on the row...

Comment: @sandeeprawat,sorry i am new to sql server, can you provide some easy syntax to do that ?

Comment: What is the **table structure**? Which of the columns is the primary key??

Comment: Read Dan Guzman's [article about this.](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach testing first will fall foul of concurrent updates if you don't take steps to serialise the transaction (don't) or lock the row.

It seems like you're doing a `[MERGE]` which is the correct way to approach this:

[Safe solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219952/safe-solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server-2016)

Answer (score 0):

Try using "sp_executesql" with parameters. It executes a Transact-SQL statement for being built dynamically.

You can find usage and detailed information here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx