# Insert data and check for duplicate records

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
            string checkstring = @"SELECT Count(*) FROM Items WHERE itemno = @itemno";  
            string insertstring = @"INSERT INTO Items (itemno, categ, name, quant, price) VALUES (@itemno, @categ, @name, @quant, @price)";  

            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data 

            Source=PC80978273;Initial Catalog=NewUsers;Integrated Security=True");  
            myConnection.Open();  
            SqlCommand cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(insertstring, myConnection);
            SqlCommand cmdCheck = new SqlCommand(checkstring, myConnection);

            int result = (int)cmdCheck.ExecuteScalar();

            if (result > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item number already exists.");
            }
            else
            {
                cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Item has been added to the inventory.");
            }

            cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemno", txtItemNo.Text);
            cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categ", cmbCategory.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
            cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quant", txtQuantity.Text);
            cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", txtPrice.Text);

            myConnection.Close();
```

How do I check for a duplicate record (itemno) and add  an error message before inserting data into my database?
An error code is dispayed

> "must declare the scalar variable "@itemno"

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: you are missing `cmdCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemno", txtItemNo.Text);` before executing `cmdCheck`

Comment: As for validating if the value is a duplicate entry. Use a try catch exception method.

Comment: Try `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` or rewriting this to single insert-select statement.

Comment: Also take a look on comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601636/sql-server-error-violation-of-primary-key-constraint-pk-table-if-not-exis/40603340#40603340

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define commands parameters, before execution of the commands:

```
SqlCommand cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(insertstring, myConnection);
SqlCommand cmdCheck = new SqlCommand(checkstring, myConnection);

cmdCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemno", txtItemNo.Text);

cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemno", txtItemNo.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categ", cmbCategory.SelectedItem.ToString());
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quant", txtQuantity.Text);
cmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", txtPrice.Text);

int result = (int)cmdCheck.ExecuteScalar();

//do other stuff
```